# unable to add html tags and associated data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been using jQuery for a short period of time & currently I am working with a website where user will log in and then jQuery will get the data from the server and append it to the existing html code. I have searched a lot in stackoverflow for this and my current code is actually the summary of what I have learnt fro here. I have tried with the load function but later I saw it has been deprecated.

My intention is to add the data after the file is loaded or by any how enable users to see the data. I also need to add id so that I can get to add certain behavior for later. Both of this functions can be accessed from both html file (index.html and profile.html > profile.html will be loaded after login)

My code is given below.

```
function changePage(mainArray, length)
{
    location.href="temp.html";
    addData(mainArray, length);
}



$(function() {

    function addData(mainArray, length)
    {
        alert("entry 1");
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var id1 = "h3"+i;
            var id2 = "p"+i;

            var newHeader= $('<h3></h3>'); //create a new h3
            $(newHeader).attr('id', id1); //set the id attribute of newHeader
            $(newHeader.html(mainArray["title"][i])); //set the innerHtml of the header
            var newPara = $('<p></p>'); //create a new p
            $(newPara).attr('id', id2); //set p id attribute
            $(newPara).html(mainArray["desc"][i]); //add descr
            $('#div1').append(newHeader);
            $('#div1').append(newPara); //add them to dom.
        }
        $("h3").text("View Summary");
        console.log("does it work?");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question *could* be a bit more descriptive, but my understanding is that you're performing an asynchronous request with jquery, then appending some elements to the DOM containing some part of the response. You reference 'adding data after file is loaded', that would probably mean you need to put your code inside of the basic document ready function of jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //your code here
});
```

-shorthand version

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Now, the meat of your question is adding the elements after we get the data. Try something closer to this:

```
function addData(mainArray, length)
{
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    var id1 = "h3"+i;
    var id2 = "p"+i;

    var newHeader= $('<h3></h3>'); //create a new h3
    $(newHeader).attr('id', id1); //set the id attribute of newHeader
    $(newHeader.html(mainArray["title"][i]); //set the innerHtml of the header
     var newPara = $('<p></p>'); //create a new p
     $(newPara).attr('id', id2); //set p id attribute
     $(newPara).html(mainArray["desc"][i]); //add descr
     $('#div1').append(newHeader);$('#div1').append(newPara); //add them to dom.

    }
    $("h3").text("View Summary");
    console.log("does it work?");
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code with the information u have given... but same result exist. My new html file is not updating. i have edited the question with update version of code.

Comment: is there a possibility that $("#div1") is hidden, or being placed outside of/beneath another element?

Comment: no. div is not hidden. its inside the body element. and there is only one element which is div inside that body element